# Subdomain forward to another host

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, host, forward

I have 2 hosts, with standard cPanel access, both are on the same server (shared hosting). I'm trying to set it up so that a subdomain forwards to the other host. Example set up:

- **Host1:** http://www.mywebsite.com
- **Host2:** http://123.123.123.123/~stuff/  (has no domain name)

I want stuff.mywebsite.com to forward to 123.123.123.123/~stuff/.

I can already do this, and there are a bunch of ways to do it, however, what I am really trying to do is forward the subdomain but keep stuff.mywebsite.com in the address bar, not a 301 redirect, or domain redirect.

I've seen things like "URL Masking", "Stealth Redirection", "URL Hiding", but I only need it for the one subdomain, not the entire domain. I would still need www.mywebsite.com to work as normal.

So, basically, I want my second host to look and act like it's a subdomain of my first host. I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I have not been able to figure out how?

Comment: Can you not add a Cname for that sub domain which points to the IP of your second host?

Comment: There will be an option like URL Redirects in domain admin panel. Have you checked with that ?

Comment: @Michael Fourre Yep, I tried adding a CNAME record, but I can't get it to work. What else do I need to do? It's shared hosting, so both have the same IP.

Comment: @Ranzit All the domain redirect options I have, simply redirects all traffic. I still need the rest of the site accessible. Only the one sub domain to be forwarded.